# Select all and clear all selection checkbox

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm implementing functions of notifications like default messages application in android. Now I'm doing the multiple message deletion by adding checkbox in which I'm using one common checkbox to select all messages in the list. But I can not check the listview checkbox which is in getview of CustomAdpter.

```
class customListAdpter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context ctx;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    TextView sender, message;

    customListAdpter(Context context) {
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new NotifiCation().senderlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int pos, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkboxlist, null);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_chck);
            sender = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_senderno);
            message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_msg);
        }
        sender.setText("" + new NotifiCation().senderlist.toArray()[pos]);
        message.setText("" + new NotifiCation().msglist.toArray()[pos]);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (buttonView.isChecked()) {

                }

            }

        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

And this is my main activity. Here I have the main checkbox.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.delete_notifications);
    db = new DB(NotificationsDelete.this);
    notifications = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_with_ckbox);
    selectAll = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.btn_checkall);
    done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_notification_delete);
    notifications.setAdapter(new customListAdpter(con));
    selectAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton chkbox, boolean arg1) {
            if (chkbox.isChecked() == true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < new NotifiCation().senderlist.size(); i++) {
                    //notifications.setItemChecked(i, true);
                    customListAdpter adpter=new  customListAdpter(con);
                    adpter.checkBox.setChecked(true);
                }
            } else {
                // new customListAdpter(con).checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }

        }
    });
    done.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling notifyDataSetChanged() after you handle onCheckedChanged() of selectAll checkbox field.